# How to add row start from certain column?

Tags: r, rbind

I have a data for example

```
ID Phenotype SNP1 SNP2 SNP3 .....SNP100
 1  1         0    2    1          0
 2  1         0    0    1          2
```

For each SNP I calculate a certain value which I have in matrix

```
           [,1]
 SNP1      0.1
 SNP2      0.5
 SNP3      0.2
  :
 SNP100    0.3
```

So now, I want to insert these values in the original data above so that I could sort the data (rank) it later.

```
ID Phenotype SNP1 SNP2 SNP3 .....SNP100
NA  NA        0.1  0.5  0.2       0.3
 1  1         0    2    1          0
 2  1         0    0    1          2
```

Comment: It is not clear about the calculation.  If you want to convert this to `long` format, try `library(reshape2);melt(df1, id.var=c('ID', 'Phenotype'))` and then do the calculation grouped by 'ID' and 'Phenotype'.

Comment: Hi @Shima. I'm not totally clear how you want the final data frame to look. Please can you edit your question to show how the finished object should look. Do you want to replace the values in your df with the ones in the lookup matrix?

Comment: Thank you both. I have edited the last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just `rbind`

```
 rbind(data.frame(ID=NA, Phenotype=NA, t(m1[,1])), df1)
 #   ID Phenotype SNP1 SNP2 SNP3
 #1 NA        NA  0.1  0.5  0.2
 #2  1         1  0.0  2.0  1.0
 #3  2         1  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, Phenotype = c(1L, 1L), 
 SNP1 = c(0L, 
 0L), SNP2 = c(2L, 0L), SNP3 = c(1L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", 
 "Phenotype", 
 "SNP1", "SNP2", "SNP3"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -2L))

 m1 <- structure(c(0.1, 0.5, 0.2), .Dim = c(3L, 1L), 
 .Dimnames = list(c("SNP1", "SNP2", "SNP3"), NULL))
```